# Android: how to get an image of a location with latitude and longitude

Tags: android, dictionary, mkmapsnapshotter

On iOS, when we have a location's latitude and longitude, we can use MKMapSnapshotter to create an image. How to achieve this on Android?

In the screenshot below from an iOS app, a snapshot of the map can be created with a latitude and a longitude.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "an image of a location"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "google static map" to get an image with location by coordinates.

You can load the generated image by creating a URL request, for example:

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=15&size=300x300&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY"
```

Furthermore, you can dive into the documentation of static maps.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully I'll try this within the next week and let you know if this works